# SQL return error within PHP

Tags: php, sql

I use GET to get the id of a result.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

I then use the following code:

```
        <?
    $q = $database->friendlyDetails($id);
    while( $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q) )
    {
        $hu = $row['home_user'];
        $ht = $row['home_team'];
        $hs = $row['home_score'];
        $au = $row['away_user'];
        $at = $row['away_team'];
        $as = $row['away_score'];
        $game = $row['game'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $match = $row['match_report1'];
        $compid = $row['compid'];
        $date = $row['date_submitted'];
        $sub = $row['user_submitted'];
    }
    ?>
```

And friendDetails-

```
   function friendlyDetails($i)
   {
   $q = "SELECT *
        FROM ".TBL_SUB_RESULTS." 
        INNER JOIN    ".TBL_FRIENDLY."
        ON ".TBL_FRIENDLY.".id = ".TBL_SUB_RESULTS.".compid
        WHERE ".TBL_SUB_RESULTS.".id = '$i'";
   return mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
   }
```

For some reason, the code will only return what is under id =1. 
Can anyone see anything obvious I am doing wrong?

EDIT
SUB RESULTS TABLE

id | compid |home_user | home_team | away_user | away_team | home_score |away_score | report1 | date | submitted

FRIENDLY TABLE

id | name | game

Comment: what does your database look like? can you post a few rows?

Comment: You might also want to sanitize the input.  Running a query with the raw contents of `$_GET['id']` is dangerous.

Comment: It will only return something when there is a row with id = 1 in sub results. And whenever i click on something with a row id 3, it will return id -1 information. Very strange. Ill post some DB stuff above in an EDIT

Comment: Don't know if this is related but as `$id` is probably not a string value, it should not be enclosed into single quotes.

Comment: Ahhh, didnt know that.
But no, hasnt made any difference.
It will only read the first line of sub results which is obviously id = 1

Comment: You should echo your query string as the first debugging step. I think you malformed it.

Comment: Are you sure that you have corresponding entries for the join to work?    If not, the result will be empty

Comment: I cant get my head around this. It only ever wants to deal with id = 1. I have no idea????

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN? Try this,

```
function friendlyDetails($i) {
    $q = "SELECT *
          FROM ".TBL_SUB_RESULTS." 
          LEFT JOIN ".TBL_SUB_RESULTS."
          ON ".TBL_SUB_RESULTS.".compid = ".TBL_FRIENDLY.".id
          WHERE ".TBL_SUB_RESULTS.".id = $i";
    return mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
}
```

Comment: Tried this, still didnt work.
I cant get my head around this. It only ever wants to deal with id = 1. I have no idea????

Comment: In your database....i assume that there are multiple values for compid in the first table....and those are related to the id in the FRIENDLY TABLE? What value is coming in from the $_GET? and are there more then 1 of those values in the compid col?

Comment: Yeah, if id=1 from GET, the query will return the correct values.
BUT, if i then go, id = 2, the values returned are still the same as id = 1. So it's almost returning id = 1 everytime. If there is no id = 1, nothing is returned. The values in compid can be 1,2,3,4,5 depending on whether its in the friendly table.

Comment: I have now fixed it, put the GET directly into the function rather than through a variable. And it works.
Thats so strange....